# Noether Normalization Steps

Tags: commutative-algebra

I'm trying to calculate the Noether normalization of some rings (suppose $K$ is a field with $0$ characteristic). The first one is $K[x,y,z]/(x^2y+xz+z)$. I know it's possible to make an algorithm to solve this problem in general, also I'm concerned in showing that $x^2y+xz+z$ is irreducible (so $\dim(K[x,y,z]/(x^2y+xz+z)) = \dim(V(x^2y+xz+z))$, right? ).

I want to know the **steps** necessary in order to solve this problem (no Groebner basis). I already did some search here but I didn't find an explicity explanation about how to get the Noether normalization. Thanks.

**PS:** I'm not asking you to solve my problem, just to show the general steps. After that I can go by myself. You can use this problem (or another) as an example of how the steps should be done. I have much more rings here to work with, so there is nothing special about this one.

Comment: Ok, but how do you know the dimension? More generally, how do I proceed to determine the dimension.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The noether normalization is an inductive process on the number of generators of an affine $k$--algebra $A=k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$.

At first you check if the $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ are algebraically independent over the field $k$. If they are, you are finished.

Otherwise you have a polynomial $f(x_1,\ldots,x_n) = 0$ that is fulfilled by the $x_i$.

Your next goal ist to find an automorphism $\phi:A \to A$ mit $x_i \mapsto y_i$, $y_i \in A$, so that $f(x_1,\ldots,x_n) = 0$ is mapped to $g(y_1,\ldots,y_n) = 0$ where $g$ has the form

$$(**) \quad\quad y_1^N + a_{1}(y_2,\ldots,y_n) y_1^{N-1} + \cdots + a_N(y_2,\ldots,y_n)$$

This shows you explicitly that $A=k[y_1,\ldots,y_n]$ is integral over the subring $B=k[y_2,\ldots,y_n]$ and you can now inductively proceed as $B$ is an affine $k$--algebra with one generator less.

Now back to the decisive step of choosing $\phi$, so that $y_1$ is "singled out" in $g(y_1,\ldots,y_n) = 0$.

There are essentially two substitutions used. One is more general and the other applies if $k$ is infinite (or algebraically closed).

Let $f(x_1,\ldots,x_n) = \sum a_{i_1,\ldots,i_n} x_1^{i_1} \cdot \cdots \cdot x_n^{i_n}$ and let without restriction of generality $x_1$ appear explicitly in $f$.

Then choose $x_1 = y_1$ and $x_i = y_i + y_1^{D^{i-1}}$. Then

$$
\begin{multline}
x_1^{i_1} \cdots x_n^{i_n} \mapsto y_1^{i_1} y_1^{D^1 i_2} y_1^{D^2 i_3} 
\cdots y_n^{D^{n-1} i_n} + r(y_1,y_2,\ldots,y_n) = \\
y_1^{i_1 + D i_2 + D^2 i_3 + \cdots + D^{n-1} i_n} + r(y_1,\ldots,y_n)
\end{multline}
$$
where the power of $y_1$ in $r$ is lower than $N_{i_1,\ldots,i_n} = i_1 + D i_2 + \cdots + D^{n-1} i_n$.

Now if you choose $D$ bigger then the biggest occuring $i_\nu$ of the exponents, all the $N_{i_1,\ldots,i_n}$ are different (think $D$--adic integers) and the biggest one is the $N$ of the formula (**) above.

This was the most general substitutions, which works regardless of the nature of $k$.

The other one is $x_1 = y_1$ and $x_i = y_i + \alpha_i y_1$, where $\alpha_i \in k$. Then you get

$$
\begin{multline}
x_1^{i_1} \cdot \cdots \cdot x_n^{i_n} \mapsto \alpha_2^{i_2} \cdots \alpha_n^{i_n} y_1^{i_1+\cdots+i_n}  + r(y_1,\ldots,y_n)
\end{multline}
$$

where the degree of $y_1$ in $r$ is less than $M_{i_1,\ldots,i_n} = i_1 + \cdots + i_n$. If now

$$f = f_d + f_{d-1} + \cdots + f_0$$

is the splitting into homogeneous components, then

$$g(y_1,\ldots,y_n) = f_d(1,\alpha_2,\ldots,\alpha_n) y_1^d + r(y_1,\ldots,y_n)$$

where the degree of $y_1$ in $r(y_1,\ldots,y_n)$ is less than $d$.

So you have again $g$ in the form $(**)$ when you choose $\alpha_i$ such that
$f_d(1,\alpha_2,\ldots,\alpha_n) \neq 0$ which is always possible if $k$ is infinite.

Comment: In the example I showed, I should write $K[x,y,z]/(x^2y+xz+z) = K[x_1, x_2,...]$ and then use the procedure you described. I'm ok with that and I know in some special cases ( like $K[x,y]/(xy-1) \cong K[x,x^{-1}]$ ) how to write affine algebras this way. But in general I don't know, is there some general procedure for this too? Thank you.

Comment: No, you start with $K[x,y,z]/(f)$ and take $f$ as the $f$ from above. Then you do the coordinate transform and get $K[x_1,y_1,z_1]/g(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ where $g$ is monic in $x_1$. In your case you are ready then. In general you start with $K[X_1,\ldots,X_n]/I$ then pick a $f$ from $I$, do the transform, get $K[Y_1,\ldots,Y_N]/J$ where $Y_1$ fulfills the monic polynomial $g$ you got from $f$. Next you determine $J \cap K[Y_2,\ldots,Y_n] = J'$ by a grobner base calculation and continue with $K[Y_2,\ldots,Y_n]/J'$.

Comment: Ok. Taking my example again to make this ideas concrete, I did the second transformations, with $ t = y - ax$, $w = z - bx$, for some $a,b$ in $K$. Then $f(x,t,w) = x^2t + xw + w = -ax^3 + xy^2  + xz - bx^2 + z - bx$, and from this I know that $K[x,y,z]/(x^2y+xz+z)$ is integral over $K[t + (f), w + (f) ]$ for $a^{-1}f(x,t,w) \in (f)$ is monic. I guess my $K[t + (f), w + (f) ]$ is $K[Y_2,Y_3]$ in your comment, but it's not clear how I determine your $J$ and continue the calculation. I just need to clarify this details once (and usually I understand better with concrete examples).

Comment: Actually your $K[t+(f),w+(f)]$ is $K[Y_2,Y_3]/J$ in my comment and $J$ is simply the image of $I$ under the automorphism $\phi:A \to A$ in the main text (that means, apply the variable change to the generators of $I$ and get the generators of $J$. Then proceed with grobner bases as indicated.

Comment: Is this problem so difficult or I'm just being too dumb? I have no idea how to get $J$ from $I$ "by hand". In my course we are not using Grobner bases, so there has to be another way.

Comment: To get $J$ from $I$ is trivial. As I explained, just apply the substitutions that comprise $\phi$ to the generators of $I$ and get the generators of $J$ (in your case these were $t = y - a x$ and $w = z - b x$). But to compute $J'$ you will usually use a grobner base calculation (at least I do not see how to avoid it).